# Vercel deployment throws "Error: Cannot find module '@next/env'"

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, web-deployment, vercel

I've been trying to debug this error for so long now... [Screenshot from Vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfi2D.png) I have a .env file in my root directory. I'm completely new to web deployment so I wasn't quite sure about what to put in the .env file either. The directory which Vercel's error message points to `/vercel/path0/node_modules/next-sitemap/bin/next-sitemap` isn't even a directory in my root folder for this project.

EDIT: This is the project's file structure. [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Gxi.png)

EDIT2: The package.json file

```
  "name": "landing-page",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.0.7",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^2.7.5",
    "globby": "^11.0.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "9.5.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.5.4",
    "npm": "^8.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "rc-drawer": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.1.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.6",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.0",
    "react-stickynode": "^3.0.3",
    "theme-ui": "^0.3.1",
    "typeface-dm-sans": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.6.203",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your folder and file project structure,;-)

Comment: what do you use yarn or npm?

Comment: @MarioG8 Sorry I'm new to sharing stuff on stack overflow. I use npm and even overrode the build prompt on Vercel to 'npm run build'. Problem is, running npm run build on local gives the same error at a different directory (next instead of vercel)

Comment: @MarioG8 I've added a screenshot of my file structure

Comment: which version of next are you using?

Comment: @whygee It's an older project template I'm building off of, I've included my package.json above but npm --version is 8.2.0 and next --version is 9.5.3

Comment: Try updating next to version 11, my guess it would fix it

Comment: @whygee The package-lock.json has the npm version as "^8.2.0" so it won't let me upgrade next beyond 9.5.3
Can I just delete package-lock.json, update npm, update next, and then regenerate a new package-lock.json??

Comment: yes, I doubt there is a way around that

Answer (score 0):

Your **project** does not have  `package-lock.json` file. This most likely causes the `error`.

1. Remove `node_modules` directory from your root project directory.
   *Below is an example of how the project should look like.*

[image]

2. Run `npm install` again.
3. Now you should have the `package-lock.json` file in your root project directory.
4. Try to `deploy` your app without any issue.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, it does have a package-lock.json. It just wasn't included in the screenshot. I didn't realize it was cut off, my apologies. Thank you for the detailed answer though!